# Problems with installation of Django Virtual Enviroment

Tags: python, django, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I´m new in Python and Django and I'm trying to create a virtual enviroment for work with these two. I'm on Windows and when I try to create the virtual enviroments with the command

`conda create --name myDjangoEnv django`

this error shows up:

```
WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'C:\Users\Paul Miranda\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv'
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic.
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

[image: Image of the error]

I have tried turning off the firewall and create it in the C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 path because the possible issue with the spaces in the user name, but neither of the two works.
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the Anaconda Prompt application. In my case the commands doesn't work with the Windows CMD but they worked in the Anaconda Promt.